# MySQL views usage

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Simply put, I have a database *tweets* that contains a tweet's text, time posted, and location (U.S. state). I also have an application written in Java that pulls from that table and generates a file containing a count of tweets for a given keyword for a given time period for a given state. For example, say I have a keyword *apple*, there is a count of the number of times the word apple appeared in a tweet for a given period of time (1 day) for a given state, and then successive entries for every other state for that time period. I want to somehow create a system where when I update the tweets table, the counts are updated accordingly, using my application written in Java.

My question is:

1) Would views be a sufficient way to do this? Possibly a view of the time period and state from the tweets table and a count generated from my application?

2) If not views, is there another better, more efficient way to do this, and could you briefly explain your reasoning so I can do this on my own with your brief explanation?

Comment: You could use a view, but I suspect you are asking how to generate the results faster, which a view won't accomplish.

Comment: I simply want to know the best method to go about and how to organize the code for doing the task I have stated with the given parameters.

Comment: I'd say yes, use a view or a collection of views, but if you are looking for individual words, you will likely want to use Full Text Search: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html. so that way you can create a view with each of the individual words you are looking for.